# A probability question - help with understanding

Tags: probability

There are 14 balls in a box, numbered 1-14. 5 of them are being chosen randomly.
What is the probability of getting a sum larger than or equal to 25 among two biggest numbers we've chosen?

I understand that there are 4 of those possibilities in total, meaning:

13+12

14+11

14+12

14+13

I'm having a hard time understanding the solution I'm provided with, though, which is:

$$\frac{\binom{12}3+\binom{11}3+\binom{10}3+\binom{11}3}{\binom{14}5}$$

I understand where $$\binom{14}5$$ comes from (I choose 5 out of 14 balls),but I have no idea what the numerator in the solution means. I'd be glad if someone could explain it to me!

Comment: I don't understand where $\binom {12}3$ comes from.  I'd have expected $\binom {14}5$.

Comment: Did you mean to say that you chose $3$ balls?

Comment: I didn't even notice that, sorry, became pretty tired solving probability problems. Fixed now.

Comment: Well, all the threes look wrong.  If, say, you want to just look at the collections with all values $≤12$ that's $\binom {12}5$.

Comment: @lulu  No, there are $\binom{12}{3}$ ways to choose 5 balls so 13 and 14 are the largest numbers.  The other 3's come from the other three combinations that make 25 or more.

Comment: The threes are actually in the solution I'm provided with, it's possibly a typo in the book but I doubt they were wrong.

Comment: @saulspatz  Agreed.  I was trying to make the sum $<25$ for whatever reason.

Comment: @lulu If you're like me, it's probably too much time spent on this site :-)

Comment: @saulspatz  no doubt!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right about what the highest numbers must be, and you're right about the denominator.  What's missing is how to count the ways that the highest numbers come up.  Let's say that the highest numbers are $13$ and $14$.  The others can be any three numbers from the balls numbered $1-12,$ so the are $\binom{12}{3}$ combinations.  This explains the first term in the numerator.  The other three terms come from the other three sums you found.

I'll leave it to you to finish.

Comment: That explains everything, thank you.